# StartCoroutine in a static member Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerable

Question

I have two scripts, one that grabs information from the other and sends information

Example :

Usage

```
var savedWeapons = PlayerSave.GetWeapons();
```

Now PlayerSave does this

```
public static string GetWeapons()
{
    StartCoroutine (GetData ("weapon", "testname"));
    return returner;
}

IEnumerator GetData(string type, string accountName)
{
    var form = new WWWForm ();
    form.AddField ("hash", hash);
    form.AddField ("name", accountName);
    form.AddField ("type", type);
    WWW w = new WWW (URL, form);
    yield return w;
    if (w.error != null) {
        //Show Error 
        Debug.Log(w.error);
        returner = w.error;
        w.Dispose();
    }
    else {
        Debug.Log(w.text);
        returner = w.text;
        w.Dispose();
    }
}
```

So basically it gets it from the database. However I get this error

```
Assets/Scripts/Scripts/PlayerSave.cs(53,19): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member 'PlayerSave.GetData(string, string)'
```

But if i take away the static member away it gives me an error in the script calling for the weapon.

Any help?

Comment: Can you show us the code at `Assets/Scripts/Scripts/PlayerSave.cs(32,19)`, because I don't see any `SendData(string, string)` method. I suspect you're looking in the wrong place? You'll also need to make `PlayerSave.GetData(string, string)` static as well, if it's being called from another static method.

Comment: Editted code sorry copied the wrong error there is a problem with the SendData as well but it's the same problem

Comment: The issue is a little clearer now. PlayerSave inherits from MonoBehaviour. So the StartCoroutine method requires an instance of PlayerSave. `static` methods require that all variables and methods also be static, which in this case, StartCoroutine isn't.

Comment: I use an asset from the Asset Store called More Effective Coroutines. It's great. And the benefit in this case is that you don't need to inherit from a MonoBehaviour. Here's the [link](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/more-effective-coroutines-free-54975).

Comment: I tried doing what was the answer here : https://answers.unity.com/questions/1207534/startcoroutine-in-a-public-static-void.html but it which gave me this runtime error `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayerSave.GetWeapon () (at Assets/Scripts/Scripts/PlayerSave.cs:53)` @MilanEgonVotrubec

Comment: Static methods can't call non-static methods without first having an instance.

Comment: @Draco18s I've tried Singletons nothing seems to be working

Comment: You need to call the instance from your singleton: `StartCoroutine (instance.GetData ("weapon", "testname"));` Which, of course, only works if you have a single instance of this class...

Comment: A singleton approach should work. How are you setting up your singleton? And I still suggest using [MEC](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/more-effective-coroutines-free-54975).